# Woocommerce product image gets cut off

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

Please see the 2 images. in woocommerce product list product image is not appearing as orginal. they are getting cut off. anyone can tell me how can I fix this. thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display`

- Catalog image
- Single Product image
- Product Thumbnails

After update thumbnails you need to update image in gallery with help `Regenerate Thumbnails` https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: I did this but yet they remain same.

Comment: @ZiaBablu Did you update all image? Can you try create new product and upload new photo?

Comment: Hi Nikita, yes I uploaded new product but nothing happened. I am worried about that.

Comment: hi nikita, thank for trying to help. problems solved. there was a problem with theme option.

Comment: @ZiaBablu If I helped you select my answer as correct, please. Thank you

Comment: @ZiaBablu Please let know others what was your theme option. So that other can get insight about your problem.

Answer (score 3):

depending on which themes you have installed and which version of woocommerce, it might be under Customizer, you get a link inside a message when you go to Woocommerce->Settings->Products.

> http://host/wp-admin/customize.php?autofocus%5Bpanel%5D=woocommerce

Something like that. I can't figure out the way to get there other than through this link.

The reason for cutoff images is not so much the size as the aspect ratio. You can choose 'Uncropped' to keep the original one.

Answer (score 1):

In Thumbnail Cropping, under Appearance > Customize > Woocommerce > Product Images, you can choose from these options:

**1:1**: Images will be cropped into a square.
**Custom**: Images will be cropped to a custom aspect ratio.
**Uncropped**: mages will display using the aspect ratio in which they were uploaded.

Keep in mind if your images are in different sizes, generated thumbnails will get either cropped ( options 1:1, and custom) or they will be in different sizes (Uncropped option), which may alter your shop grid layout.

To fix that you will have to manually edit your images before uploading them your store. This may seem ok for a store with few products but it can be a tedious and time-wasting task for a store with thousands of products. To automatically fix that I suggest using this  plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-image-resize/